# Google AppMaker : Timeout for server-side script calls

Tags: google-app-maker

I am trying to call an external service from a Google AppMaker server-side script using the FetchUrl function.

I get a timeout after only 1 minute (the service takes ~1min 30s to run and respond). From [the Google documentation on quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) I see the timeout should be 6 min.

Is there an option at application level or somewhere else to increase this timeout to get at least the one we see on the quotas list ?

Server-side logs:

```
2019-01-21 10:41:06.090 CET
Trying to connect to https://europe-west1-***
2019-01-21 10:42:06.080 CET
Exception: Timeout: https://europe-west1-*** at myFunction
```